# Symfony2 impersonate listener with parameters injection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, switch-user

i'm currently working on a custom logic impersonate listenener.

i overrided the Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener because i would like to perform call to some entities repositories ( not User entity )  before authorize the switch event :

for example , i would like to authorize the switch if and only if the user to impersonate has already gave rights to user requesting for the switch.

is it possible to inject new parameters such as doctrine service or some arrays values to an overrided listener ?

the call to my custom SwitchUserListenener :

```
in services.yml

parameters:
    security.authentication.switchuser_listener.class: acme\appBundle\EventListener\SwitchUserListener
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may be here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L597

The service `security.authentication.switchuser_listener` defined by Symfony is an abstract service.  It is not actually the service being used as the listener, but it is the same class.

Go up in the code a bit to:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L233

```
foreach ($firewalls as $name => $firewall) {
    list($matcher, $listeners, $exceptionListener) = $this->createFirewall($container, $name, $firewall, $authenticationProviders, $providerIds);
```

This is the name of the firewall you created where the user switch will be possible.

Now you have a couple of options to override the listener.
You can continue to override the class parameter, then manipulate the arguments as Symfony is already doing:

```
$listener->replaceArgument(1, new Reference($userProvider));
$listener->replaceArgument(3, $id);
$listener->replaceArgument(6, $config['parameter']);
$listener->replaceArgument(7, $config['role']);
```

Or more simply, compile additional method calls in your extension.

The other solution, would be to create a `CompilerPass` which systematically deletes the original listeners and replaces them with your own.  This might be achievable in your own bundles extension provided it is loaded after the `SecurityBundle`.

```
$container->removeDefinition($id);
```

EDIT:

Another solution, perhaps more simple than the above, is to create another event listener.
One which fires on the request.  The important thing here is the listener must have a higher priority to the listeners you are overriding (I used listener(s) because there are potentially more than one switch user listener).

The tricky part will be getting a list of the overridden listeners IDs, because you are going to need to loop over them and call your own methods to inject your new dependencies after the listeners are instantiated, but before they triggered.